# Batch for writing month as numeral to txt file

Tags: batch-file

I need a batch file that when run it saves the current month as a numeral to a text file;

ie; if it's April, it saves 04 to month.txt.

Also, it has to overwrite any other text that's already in the file.

ie; instead of the text finally looking like this:

04

04

04

04

-it just shows the most recent '04'. Also, no additional spaces or linebreaks should be added. Just the 04 (nothing more, nothing less).

Thanks to any repliers in advance. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
@echo off
echo %date:~3,2%>month.txt
```

Comment: NO, this is wrong. _Also, it has to overwrite any other text that's already in the file._

Comment: And it should be `@echo off` instead if `echo off & cls` because there is no need to cls.

Comment: And still, `cls` is not needed. ___Please re-read the question.___ __The tag is batch-file, not cmd.__

Comment: Thanks guys for helping so quickly. It turns out sachadee's code (slightly modded) works best for me.

Answer (score 1):

There are the following problems for the task to be accomplished:

- retrieving the current month (date) in a locale-independent manner;
- *not* writing a (final) line-break to the output file;
- *not* modifying the current `ERRORLEVEL` state;

I found the following solution (see below for an explanation):

```
@echo off

rem get locale-independent date/time string (YYYYMMDDHHMMSS...) by "WMIC" command;
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('wmic OS GET LocalDateTime /VALUE') do set DAT=%%I

rem the "%DAT:~4,2%" portion extracts the month numeral;
rem instead of just "echo"-ing the month numeral, use "set /P" user prompt text,
rem because this doesn't produce a final line-break unlike "echo" does;
rem then redirect the textual output of this to the text file;
rem since "set /P" modifies the ERRORLEVEL state, let's append the "cmd /C" portion;
(echo _| set /P DAT="%DAT:~4,2%" > month.txt) & cmd /C exit %ERRORLEVEL%
```

The `set /P` command is actually intended to prompt the user for a value to be assigned to a variable. In the script only the user prompt text is used. Unlike `echo`, the display string does *not* contain a final line-break. In order not to halt the script and awaiting any user input, an arbitrary `echo` string is piped in. (I use string "_" (`echo _`) rather than just a line-break (`echo.`) because the latter sets `ERRORLEVEL` to `1`.)

Notice, that the variable assignment of `set /P` does actually *not* happen in our batch context, because the pipe creates a new context intermittently. In addition, the variable value is not of interest anyway, only the user prompt text. So you could also write `set /P DUMMY=` instead of `set /P DAT=`.

The double-quotes around the `set /P` user prompt text are needed to avoid a trailing space to be returned (even with the space before `>` removed). I do not why but I guess such might be caused by the way the redirection `>` is read by the command line interpreter.

If you are not interested in the `ERRORLEVEL` state, you may remove the `cmd /C` portion so only the part in between the parentheses is kept.
However, if you do not want the `ERRORLEVEL` state to be altered, keep the `cmd /C` portion, which restores the original `ERRORLEVEL` state, because:

- the command interpreter reads the entire line **prior to** execution of any command;
- `%ERRORLEVEL%` is expanded **immediately**, so its state prior to execution is stored;
- as soon as `set /P` is executed, the actual `ERRORLEVEL` state is modified;
- `exit %ERRORLEVEL%` sets the `ERRORLEVEL` state back to the previously stored original state;
- `cmd /C` wrapped around the `exit` command avoids the current script to be terminated;

Answer (score -1):

Well, it is impossible (for me) not to make a line break, but try this:

```
echo %date:~3,2%>expected\destination\filename.txt
```

That's my answer. Whether accept it or not, hope it helps you!

Comment: Why did you create a new variable ? You can directly use %date%.

Comment: That turns out to be true. Sorry for doing this!